# Parse html in android app

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

When I'm trying to get the site title stackoverflow all goes well, but when I try to get the title beastinvest.su nothing happens. What is the reason?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button butTest;
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        butTest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        new MyParser().execute("http://beastinvest.su/");

    }

    public class MyParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... links) {
            Document doc = null;
            String title = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(links[0]).get();
                title = doc.title();
                textView.setText(title);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad English

---

the problem is that the site AntiDDOS - query returns "To visit this site requires cookies and javacript your browser."

Answer (score 1):

Provided site (beastinvest.su) has title in Russian and contains `<meta charset="windows-1251"`. I suppose that Jsoup uses UTF-8 encoding by default during parsing routine.

Comment: I found another site with the coding windows-1251 (http://winrus.com/cpage_r.htm) and I get title from the application, I think the problem is not encoded

Comment: But its title is in English. Maybe the problem is in the combination of Russian title and windows-1251 encoding.

Comment: From the site you provided: _If you or your future readers work under a non-Russian Windows, it's not a good idea to use Cyrillic letters in the Title of your page._

Comment: I created a simple page with the encoding windows-1251 and Russian title and it works http://besplprognoz.ru/test.html

Comment: Continuing aforementioned quote: _Cyrillic title is unavailable in most cases_. Not all, but most. Apparently your stub page doesn't prove that encoding isn't the cause of misbehavior. If you provide more examples I'll reconsider my opinion.

Comment: How can I get the title beastinvest.su?

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi use below code,


   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button butTest;
    TextView textView;
    String title;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        butTest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        new MyParser().execute("http://beastinvest.su/");

    }

    public class MyParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... links) {
            Document doc = null;

            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(links[0]).get();
                title = doc.title();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
   public void onPostExecute(String result) {
       textView.setText(title);
   }
```